# Eclipse + GWT classpath error

Tags: java, eclipse, gwt

I am using Eclipse with GWT and trying to build a Web based application. I am a beginner and have no idea what this means. I tried to look in the web but no satisfactory explanation. I can only figure out that I need to edit some file, but I don't know how. Any help appreciated.

> Loading modules com.model.WebCrawler.WebCrawler
>   [ERROR] Unable to find 'com/model/WebCrawler/WebCrawler.gwt.xml' on your classpath; could be a typo, or maybe you forgot to include a
>   classpath entry for source?
>   [ERROR] shell failed in doStartup method

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a module XML file for your application to load correctly.

Take a look at the [google tutorials](http://code.google.com/intl/de-DE/webtoolkit/doc/1.6/tutorial/create.html) and search for module XML file.

If you use the gwt plugin for eclipse, you can create a sample project where the most struggling parts will be generated for you, so that you can pretty much start immediatly with your custom code.

Comment: It says to specify an entry point which has automatically been specified, its not clear what I need to change

Comment: @Prince The entry point is one of your classes which implements the EntryPoint interface and therefore has an `onModuleLoad()` method. This class has to be specified in the module XML file with full package name.

Comment: In my case, the onModuleLoad() method is specified in class WebCrawler and this is by default specified in the module XML file as com.model.myproject.client.WebCrawler I have not made any changes to the project after creating it but it is not running.

Comment: got it, restarted eclipse created a new project, seems like web server needs to be refreshed after every edit

Answer (score 0):

What you could do is create a basic GWT project with eclipse (and the GWT plugin) and check the checkbox to include the source.  That way you can look at how the files should be setup and have a working example to review.

If you are doing it from scratch, then yes, you need to name your module xml file to match your project.  That is a GWT convention.

Comment: "you need to name your module xml file to match your project." --how?